# Docker Windows 403 Forbidden Access after adding a volume to composer

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-5.4

I am new to Docker and I am trying to link up Docker with PHP. So, I follow the tutorial from this article: https://bitpress.io/simple-approach-using-docker-with-php/ and everything ran well.

Unfortunately, when I am trying to add a volume for local development to `docker-compose.yml` file, I can't open the website. It shows *403 Forbidden*: *You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 192.168.99.100 Port 8080*.

My docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravel-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
     - .:/srv/app
```

Dockfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.8-apache

MAINTAINER CC

COPY . /srv/app
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/app \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/app/public
    ServerName foo.example.com

    <Directory "/srv/app/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted

    allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything work fine when volumes is excluded. I am using Windows 10 Home Basic. Btw, where is the directory of `:/srv/app` ?

Anyone can help to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`/srv/app` is the directory on in the docker container.

The volume tag specifies how you want to mount a file system from outside your container to inside your container

`<windows machine>:<inside container>`

So the definition you have will mount the root directory (where your docker-compose file is) and all subfolders of that directory to the `/srv/app` directory in the container.

`.:/srv/app`

Your issue is that the folder you have configured to serve your php pages from, in your `vhost.conf` file, is `/srv/app/public` and on your local machine you probably don't have the file `public/index.php`

It's not that you don't have permissions it's that there is no file to serve.

If you want to check what is in the container you can run `docker-compose exec app /bin/bash` and poke around inside the container.

Comment: I do have the file at `D:\Docker Toolbox\laravel-docker\public\index.php` but not in `D:\Docker Toolbox\laravel-docker\app`. FYI, the `D:\Docker Toolbox\laravel-docker` is my PHP laravel folder.

Comment: I'd tried change the volume tag to ./:/app. It works but I have no idea why it works

Comment: It's because in the Dockerfile you copy the contents of your current directory over to the container.  You could use `./:/foo` and it would probably work.  You'll notice that when you change the `index.php` file it isn't reflected on the page

Comment: I've got it working locally, maybe you can post the logs from the container, could be something to do with saving the index.php file in windows and trying to read in linux, something to do with line endings